# Split Table Into Two Separate Tables and Set New Primary Key as a Foreign Key

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have seen posts similar to what I need, but they all fall slightly short. I'm also not sure if what I need can be done. If it cannot be done, then any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

I am reconstructing my database, and need to merge parts of three different tables into one. Currently I have three different types of tasks, let's call them *DailyTasks*, *Reviews* and *Requests*. All three tables have similar fields such as *DateCreated*, *DateCompleted*, *EstimatedHours* etc. I have created a parent table, called *Tasks*, which contains these common fields, and the other tables (*DailyTasks*, *Reviews* and *Requests*) only have fields that are specific to themselves. The child tables now also have a Foreign Key, *TaskID*, that points to the parent table. I believe this is standard database practice, correct me if I'm wrong.

Currently I am working in a test database, so I can pull the original data from the live database for testing purposes. I need to be able to pull the common fields from each table and place them in the parent table, while at the same time placing the new primary key into the *TaskID* column of the child table.

I would have like to of have used a join, but I don't believe I can insert into two tables that way while retrieving the Primary Key. My next thought if a join won't work is to use a cursor. Any help would be appreciated and I hope I've explained everything properly.

EDIT
Here are the table's fields

**TASKS** (Parent)

- TaskID (PK)
- DateCreated
- DateCompleted
- DateDue
- EstHrs
- BaselineHrs
- Notes
- Priority
- CreatedBy

**DailyTasks** (Child)

- EngTaskID (PK)
- TaskID (FK)
- ProjectID
- Description
- AssignedTo

**Requests** (Child)

- DrawingRequestID (PK)
- TaskID (FK)
- DrawingLink
- PartNumber

**Reviews** (Child)

- JobAuditID (PK)
- TaskID (FK)
- ItemNumber
- CycleTime
- ToolingRequirements

Comment: `the other tables (DailyTasks, Reviews and Requests) only have fields that are specific to themselves`  how many other fields are we talking about?  sounds like you're wanting to implement inheritance which can be a pain.  you may be better off figuring out a way to combine all three tables into one with a `TaskType` column to determine what type of task it is

Comment: if i were to see a table `Tasks` and three tables `DailyTasks, Reviews and Requests` with a `TaskId` column, I would assume that a task could have Daily Tasks, Reviews and Requests.. I wouldn't just assume it could only be one or the other.  And if that is the case then the `Tasks` table would be more like a child table with DailyTasks, Reviews and Requests being the parents

Comment: It would he helpful if you could post the ddl of what you are thinking. You certainly are not going to need a cursor here...they should be avoided for dml statements like this.

Comment: Oh I see what you are doing now. You certainly don't need a cursor. You need to use the OUTPUT clause. You will probably have to generate three statements, one for each type so you can split out the data correctly.

Comment: thank you both for your time. I've made an edit to explain my table layout. @JamieD77, I've combined tables before like you were explaining, but there were so many columns that only apply to certain tables, it seemed to get out of hand. But by all means, if that's the general accepted way, I can give it a shot.

Comment: @Sean Lange, I'll have to look into the OUTPUT clause. I've used it, but am pretty unfamiliar with it. Do you have an example of what you were thinking?

Comment: You would do an insert into the Tasks table for ONLY one of the task types. You would add an OUTPUT clause to the insert to insert the relevant values to the child for that type.

Comment: it's not a bad idea to do it this way.. this is just like having a class Tasks and another class DailyTasks that inherits from Tasks.  But like I said doing  an Inheritance type table design can be a pain to manage.  Having a `DailyTasks` with a complex type of `TaskDetails` though is a little easier to code for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a real hierarchy and thus every parent only has a single child record you could create a class like inheritance structure. With this setup you can ease things by making your PK also your foreign key to the parent table. This works nice with e.g. Entity Framework but its also simple to use when you query directly with TSQL.

Simplified the creation of the tables would look like. The parent table obviously does exist already just for completeness of the sample script):

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Tasks] (
    [Id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [CreatedBy] [nvarchar](150) NOT NULL,
    [OtherColumns] [datetime] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Tasks] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ( [Id] ASC ) 
 )

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DailyTasks] (
    [Id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [OtherColumns] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_DailyTasks] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ( [Id] ASC ) 
)

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[DailyTasks] 
ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_DailyTasks_Tasks] FOREIGN KEY([Id])
REFERENCES [dbo].[DailyTasks] ([Id])
```

With this setup you can easy do 3 inserts from your the parent table to the child tables and when you're done, drop the columns from the parent table. Something like this:

```
INSERT INTO     [dbo].[DailyTasks]
                ([Id], [OtherColumns])
SELECT          [Id], [OtherColumns]
FROM            [dbo].[Tasks]
```

Comment: I appreciate everyone's input. For the sake of marking this question as answered, I'm going to mark this as the answer, but all of you have proven to be insightful with your answers. Thank you for your time and help.